# Receiving onclientconnectionstate() - status=133 on custom Android BLE app that uses NUS service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am receiving the above error on Android BLE app while connecting to my pca10040 based board, and I developed this app with nRF Toolbox as a reference.

I am testing this on multiple Android versions and devices, out of which I dont face any problem on motorolla devic, or nexus device (android 7) or on one plus one with android 6.

I am specifically facing this issue on redmi 3s prime with android 6.0.1. On this device My connection handler will wait for some time and then it throws this error.

I have attached the logs with testing different devices:

```
    **Note : 1 = Connected state
         2 = Connecting state

Mi Redme 3s Prime (6.0.1 - Marshmallow)
Result: Fail

04-18 11:56:59.462 8852-8852/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: D0:35:52:F8:A9:59, auto: false
04-18 11:56:59.462 8852-8852/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
04-18 11:56:59.462 8852-8852/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=dd2097ce-ff94-42e4-a454-4c4401aa5482
04-18 11:56:59.466 8852-8892/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
04-18 11:56:59.467 8852-8852/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 2
04-18 11:57:00.740 8852-8888/com.demo.bledoorlock V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-18 11:57:29.490 8852-8992/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=5 device=D0:35:52:F8:A9:59
04-18 11:57:29.491 8852-8852/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 2


Mi Redme 2 Prime (5.1.1 - Lollipop)
Result: Pass

04-18 11:54:13.871 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: D0:35:52:F8:A9:59, auto: false
04-18 11:54:13.871 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
04-18 11:54:13.871 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=cb431bbb-bc5e-459b-bdcf-f7ed1929fa01
04-18 11:54:13.871 25251-25580/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
04-18 11:54:13.871 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 2
04-18 11:54:14.071 25251-25267/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=D0:35:52:F8:A9:59
04-18 11:54:14.071 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 1
04-18 11:54:14.091 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: D0:35:52:F8:A9:59
04-18 11:54:14.091 25251-25251/com.demo.bledoorlock I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
04-18 11:54:14.091 25251-25580/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=D0:35:52:F8:A9:59 Status=0
04-18 11:54:14.101 25251-25580/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e enable: true


Oneplus One (6.0.1 - Marshmallow)
Result: Pass

04-18 11:58:16.768 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: D0:35:52:F8:A9:59, auto: false
04-18 11:58:16.768 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
04-18 11:58:16.768 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=a3af82f0-c095-4b06-a1fb-479d7d5f715e
04-18 11:58:16.770 28661-28674/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
04-18 11:58:16.777 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 2
04-18 11:58:17.073 28661-28675/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=D0:35:52:F8:A9:59
04-18 11:58:17.074 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock I/System.out: 1
04-18 11:58:17.086 28661-28661/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: D0:35:52:F8:A9:59
04-18 11:58:17.089 28661-28674/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=D0:35:52:F8:A9:59 Status=0
04-18 11:58:17.092 28661-28674/com.demo.bledoorlock D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e enable: true
04-18 11:58:17.159 28661-28697/com.demo.bledoorlock V/RenderScript: 0xaeee3000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
04-18 11:58:17.571 28661-28693/com.demo.bledoorlock V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: You should show some code. For example, when do you print FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service?

Comment: FA is for Firebase..! I have integrated firebase library so this get printed..
I have problem with Bluetooth

Comment: Is there any solution..??

Comment: You should contact Redmi 3s support? It's obviously their software that fails when it shouldn't.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: You could post some code. Are you scanning before connecting? Are you bonded?